# Ajuda em Python: Exercicio Ano escolar

Tags: python

Olá,

Estou precisando de ajuda para um exercício em *Python* que é o seguinte:

Exercício Ano escolar

• Escreva um programa que peça o nome e a data (ano, mês e dia) de
nascimento de uma pessoa.

• O programa deverá também pedir a data atual (ano, mês e dia).

• O ano letivo começa em 15 de Setembro. As crianças com 6 anos até esse
dia entram no 1o ano. Os com 7, estão no 2o, etc.

• Com base nestas datas, você deverá determinar a idade da pessoa e indicar o ano de escolaridade em que está.

• Exemplo de resultado:

Como se chama? José

Nasceu em que ano? 2001

Nasceu em que mes? 2

Nasceu em que dia? 23

Em que ano estamos? 2009

Em que mes estamos? 4

Em que dia estamos? 9

O José tem 8 anos e está no 2º ano.

Estou com dificuldade em fazer o cálculo.

Este é o código:
[código](https://repl.it/@jpfernandes/Exercicio-3-ano-escolar)

Comment: O que fez até ao momento ? Inclua o código que tem para ser fácil de ajudar na sua real duvida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado desde já a todos os que me ajudaram.
Aqui deixo o código:

[Code](https://repl.it/@jpfernandes/Exercicio-3-ano-escolar)

Código:

```
import datetime

print('='*24)
print('Exercício 3: ano escolar')
print('='*24)

nome = input ("Como se chama? ")
ano = eval (input ("Nasceu em que ano? "))
mes = eval (input ("Nasceu em que mês? "))
dia = eval (input ("Nasceu em que dia? "))
ano_atual = eval (input ("Em que ano estamos? "))
mes_atual = eval (input ("Em que mês estamos? "))
dia_atual = eval (input ("Em que dia estamos? "))
dataNasc = datetime.date(ano, mes, dia)
dataAtual = datetime.date(ano_atual, mes_atual, dia_atual)



#Calculo da idade
idade=ano_atual-ano
if mes_atual < mes:
    idade=idade-1
elif (mes_atual == mes) and (dataAtual < dataNasc):
    idade=idade-1

#Calculo do Ano Letivo
idade_min=6
aletivo=1

if idade==idade_min:
    print ("O %s tem %d anos e está no %d ano." % (nome,idade,aletivo))
elif idade>=idade_min:
    if (mes_atual < 9 and dataNasc < 15):
        aletivo=(idade-idade_min)
        print ("O %s tem %d anos e está no %dº ano." % (nome,idade,aletivo))
    else:
        aletivo=(idade-idade_min)+1
        print ("O %s tem %d anos e está no %dº ano." % (nome,idade,aletivo))
else:
    print ("O %s tem %d anos e ainda não tem idade para andar na escola." % (nome,idade))
```

Answer (score 0):

Então, o cálculo vai se basear nas variáveis de data que o usuário vai dar input.
O ano da criança vai ser a diminuição entre a variável ano que estamos e ano de nascimento.
Sendo assim vamos chamar ano de nascimento de AN, e ano que estamos de AA(ano atual), o cálculo para isto será básico e deve ser armazenado em outra variável, id(idade).

```
id = AN - AA
```

Para determinar o ano que o indivíduo vai estar na escola você pode usar switch's, múltiplos if's, ou também(o que recomendo) percorrer um ciclo while, for, ou o qual ciclo de repetição achar melhor.

Percorrendo assim todos os anos envolvidos na questão.
Não postarei o código aqui pois é uma atividade que você deve fazer, e se eu fizer para você estarei burlando o trabalho do seu professor ;)

Boa sorte, os caminhos estão dados.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    #listas com as séries divida por níveis 
    fundamental_I = ['Primeira série', 'Segunda Série', 'Terceira Série', 'Quarta Série']
    fundamental_II = ['Quinta Série', 'Sexta Série', 'Sétima Série', 'Oitava Série']
    ensino_Medio = ['Primeira Série EM', 'Segunda Série EM', 'Terceira Série EM']

    #'ve' só facilita a escrita, ao invés de ficar escrevendo "você está na...", só printa a escrita de uma vez só.
    ve = '\nVocê está na: '
    print("Vou descobrir em qual série você está!\n ")
    seuNome = input("Qual é o seu nome? ")
    print("Certo!\n")
    anoAtual = 2018

    # o int limita o input do usuário à apenas números inteiros
    nasceu = int(input("Qual é o ano em que nasceu? "))
    dia = int(input("Em que dia? "))
    mes = int(input("Em que mês? (apenas números) "))

    # atribui o resultado do ano - data de nascimento
    idade = anoAtual - nasceu

    #fudamental I
    if idade == 7:
        print(ve)
        print([fundamental_I[0]])
    elif idade == 7+1:
        print(ve)
        print(fundamental_I[1])
    elif idade == 7+2:
        print(ve)
        print(fundamental_I[2])
    elif idade == 7+3:
        print(ve)
        print(fundamental_I[3])
    #ensino fundamental II
    if idade == 11:
        print(ve)
        print(fundamental_II[0])
    elif idade == 11+1:
        print(ve)
        print(fundamental_II[1])
    elif idade == 11+2:
        print(ve)
        print(fundamental_II[2])
    elif idade == 11+3:
        print(ve)
        print(fundamental_II[3])
    #ensino médio
    elif idade == 15:
        print(ve)
        print(ensino_Medio[0])
    elif idade == 15+1:
        print(ve)
        print(ensino_Medio[1])
    elif idade == 15+2:
        print(ve)
        print(ensino_Medio[2])
    elif idade >= 18:
        print("\nVocê concluiu o período escolar!!!")
    print('\n')
    print("%s nasceu no dia %d e no mês %d no ano: %d"% (seuNome, dia, mes, nasceu))
    print('\n')
    break
```